# Is it more efficient to use multiple computers when I have multiple GPUs?

Tags: hashpower, gpu-mining, mining-setup

I have 4 video cards: **2x 7970** & **2x 6970**.

This is a question of efficiency regarding MH/s. Simply, I would like to know which is better:

1. ~1900 MH/s on one machine
2. ~1200 MH/s and ~700 MH/s on respective machines
3. It does not matter

Could the answer please include efficiency for both solo mining and pool mining?

Comment: More efficient in terms of Hash/Second, Hash/$ or Hash/Watt?

Comment: @NickODell I reworded the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This is a question of efficiency regarding MH/s. Simply, I would like to know which is better

It doesn't matter. Every hash has an equal probability of finding a block. However, that being said, there's some hidden teeth:

- Putting graphics cards together will make them harder to cool.
- Putting them in multiple computers will use more electricity - all computers use some electricity, even at idle.

> Could the answer please include efficiency for both solo mining and pool mining?

My advice applies for both.

Comment: If I had a solution for the cooling problem, would you consider having 3 cards in one box to be the best solution?

Comment: @user4543 Yeah.